# How to print text on cmd console while task is being executed

Tags: r, windows-task-scheduler

When the windows task scheduler runs a R script, it shows a blank terminal while the script is being executed.

I would like to know if there there is any way to show some text on this terminal during that time ? For example the name of the task being executed ?

I tried by passing some args to the `Rscript` cmd but I didn't manage to print anything

Comment: I use `print("some message")` in my code to do this.

Comment: I think @cory is right. If you do not pipe the scripts messages to a log file, every message should be printed in the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

Add `options(echo = TRUE)` in your R code